# Tortoise SVN Cannot commit to repo

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I backed up my visualsvn repos from a computer and after installing visualsvn and tortoise on a new computer I imported the backedup repos. It looked ok since I could see the changes made on the first computer and use the dev branch.

When I tried to commit modifications made on the second computer I got a

> "tortoise cannot connect to the repository"

and thus not commit.

On the first machine I used to access repos through file protocol and on the new machine I got the https protocol which works fine because I can access it through browser and or tortoise repo browser.

It is just tortoise commit that keeps wanting to use the file protocol instead of the https. I assume it was imported from the backup but how can I tell tortoise to switch to http?

[image: Tortoise commit error]

[image: But it can be accessed with https from the browser]

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer:

Use TortoiseSVN, rightclick the top most folder you checked-out/or not.

Select TortoiseSVN --> Relocate.

Simply type in the new url with the choosen protocol and click OK. Without even restarting Visual studio, you can commit/update with the new url.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. You can now accept your own answer.